# Custom view (not ViewGroup) created based on xml layout (with predefined attributes)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I want to implement a custom ImageView with some predefined attributes based on the xml file. To do that I prepared a layout wrapped within `merge` tag:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
</merge>
```

And extended `ImageVie`w class:

```
public class CustomImageView extends LinearLayout{

    public ImageFormField(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ImageFormField(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public ImageFormField(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public ImageFormField(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.custom_image_view, this);
    }
}
```

It works so far, but I actually don't need that `LinearLayout` as I could extend directly from the `ImageView`. By extending `ImageView` I'd like to have the possibility to override `src` parameter from the default layout.

So I removed `merge` tag to have only `ImageView` in the layout and tried this:

```
public class CustomImageView extends AppCompatImageView{

    public ImageFormField(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ImageFormField(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public ImageFormField(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.custom_image_view, null); //can't pass root here
    }
}
```

... but the image is simply not displayed. I want to be able to use my view this way:

```
<com.my.package.CustomImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

with possibility to override `src` attribute. Is there a way to do that by inflating layout or do I have to go deep with attributes (including custom ones)?

**UPDATE**
By "overriding `src` attribute I mean that by default image will have source from its xml file, but user can use it that way to pass another value within this custom view:

```
<com.my.package.CustomImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/another_icon" />
```

Comment: I think try using src attribute with custom one in XML , it should work if you are extending Image view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide a "default" image but also allow the user to override that default by specifying the `android:src` attribute, you can do this:

```
package com.example.stackoverflow;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class CustomImageView extends AppCompatImageView {

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        if (getDrawable() == null) {
            setImageResource(R.drawable.default_image);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<!-- will display `default_image` -->
<com.example.stackoverflow.CustomImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"/>
```

Or:

```
<!-- will display `other_image` -->
<com.example.stackoverflow.CustomImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/other_image"/>
```

There's no need to inflate anything inside the custom image view, and no need to create custom attributes (though you could certainly create custom attributes and use them if you wanted to).

You could update the Java code to apply other "default" styles too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my question so maybe it's more clear. Basically I want default values for attributes in my custom view. Something like styling achieved with custom view.

Comment: @qbeck The update doesn’t make it clearer for me. You say “the user can use it that way”... what way? What does “override” mean? Which xml files are you referring to?

Comment: @qbeck I updated my answer with what I think you were looking for.